# How to disable interaction when CircularProgressIndicator is active?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

What is the correct way/approach to disable the background interaction when progress bar is active.

```
  Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
  ) {
    // Some content (when anyState is true, disable screen interaction)
    if(anyState){
       MaterialCircularProgressIndicator()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe this is to somebody's help.
I found that both [Philip Dukhov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69212026/695524) and [Ritt's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69222822/695524) answers did work. 
HOWEVER: make sure to draw to Box as very last composable element, after all other elements. 
So: e.g. first a button then the box, not the other way around.

Pretty obvious but cost my a good few hours to figure out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked out for me.

```
    if (anyState) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .clickable(
                indication = null, // disable ripple effect
                interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
                onClick = { }
            ),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 13):

You need an other box, which you can fill with a translucent background(I prefer doing so user understand why his touches are not working), and you can interrupt touches with `pointerInput`. This is exactly same technique Compose [uses](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/e2806ef8279bb446f87581e1b3d4c457e6c8c4e9/compose/material/material/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/Surface.kt#L120) to block touches under the [`Surface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Surface(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function0)).

```
if(anyState){
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.3f))
            .pointerInput(Unit) {}
    )
    CircularProgressIndicator()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should a add `clickable()` modifier to the Box when any state is true.

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .let {
              return@let if (anyState) {
                   it.clickable {}
               } else it
         },
         contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
      MaterialCircularProgressIndicator()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Transparent Background:

```
@Composable
    fun CommonProgress() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().
    background(Color.Transparent).clickable(
        indication = null, // disable ripple effect
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
        onClick = { }
    ), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(color = LocalCustomColorsPalette.current.iconColor)
    }
}
```